# Using php pointers on function?

Tags: php, function, pointers

I'm creating a website and somewhere in the code I need to query for a user attribute (ex:account state) and in the same row I have the reason, case is account state is "suspended".

I'm trying to minimize the requests to the database, so I created a function to verify account state.

```
function getAccountState($userid,$reason){}
```

What I am trying to do is if account state is "suspended" I would change the $reason to "the database reason".

I've already done that but if I change the $reason inside the function, outside the function it will not change.
I searched for "php pointers" on google but I think there is not such thing.

Is there a way to do this? Other way I'll just make another database request...

Comment: PHP doesn't have pointers or dynamic memory.  Even references aren't exactly like references you'd see in C++ (although they're used pretty much the same way).

Answer (score 2):

You could of course pass the variable by reference but as you don't seem to need it, I would just return it from the function:

```
function getAccountState($userid){
  // your code
  return $reason;
}
```

and call it like:

```
$reason = getAccountState($userid);
```

If you want to stay your code as it is now, you could [pass the variable by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php):

```
function getAccountState($userid,&$reason){}
                                 ^ like so
```

Comment: Well, I was returning the "state" attribute, so the first way is not the one i'm looking.
The second one was perfect. Thanks for the fast response !

Comment: @Ricardo Neves You could return an array or just use the second solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could consider passing it in by [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php). Or perhaps just changing the function to return the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of functions you can tell that $reason argument is passed by reference, not value. To do so, use & in front of variable:

```
function getAccountState($userid,& $reason){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for references, in PHP terminology, not pointers.

They work this way :

```
function getAccountState($userid, &$reason){  // Notice the &
    $reason = "database locked";  // Use it as a regular variable
}


getAccountState(12345, $reason);  // Here, it is written as a regular variable, but it is a ref.
echo $reason;   // echoes "database locked"
```